# Probability of rolling fewer than m distinct numbers on n sided die after k rolls

Tags: probability, statistics, dice

### Question

Suppose I have an n-sided die which I roll k times. For any given m $\le$ n, what is the probability that I roll $\le$ m distinct numbers.

### Follow-up

What is the smallest m such that I can be 99% sure there are $\le$ m distinct numbers after k rolls?

Comment: What is the *largest* $m$?  That would be $n$.  Surely you mean to ask about the *smallest* $m$ or maybe the largest $k$.

Comment: As for an approach, I suggest looking at [Stirling numbers of the second kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind).  Convince yourself that there are $\binom{n}{r}\left\{\begin{smallmatrix}m\\r\end{smallmatrix}\right\}r!$ ways to roll exactly $r$ distinct numbers out of $m$ rolls of an $n$-sided die.

Comment: Oops, you are right! Smallest m.